# Square API: Create Checkout API error

Tags: square-connect

When using the sample POSTMAN request:

```
{
  "idempotency_key": "74ae1696-b1e3-4328-af6d-f1e04d947a13",
  "order": {
    "reference_id": "my-order-001",
    "line_items": [
    {
      "name": "line-item-1",
      "quantity": "1",
      "base_price_money": {
        "amount": 1599,
        "currency": "USD"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "line-item-2",
      "quantity": "2",
      "base_price_money": {
        "amount": 799,
        "currency": "USD"
      }
    }]
  },
  "ask_for_shipping_address": true,
  "merchant_support_email": "merchant+support@website.com",
  "pre_populate_buyer_email": "buyer@email.com",
  "pre_populate_shipping_address": {
    "address_line_1": "500 Electric Ave",
    "address_line_2": "Suite 600",
    "locality": "New York",
    "administrative_district_level_1": "NY",
    "postal_code": "10003",
    "first_name": "Jane",
    "last_name": "Doe"
  },
  "redirect_url": "https://merchant.website.com/order-confirm"
}
```

I'm getting the following response:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "category": "INVALID_REQUEST_ERROR",
      "code": "INVALID_VALUE",
      "detail": "The order must have at least one line item.",
        "field": "line_items"
    }]
}
```

This is simply executing the sample POSTMAN requests available via https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2/#runningpostman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having the same issue and I reached out to Tristan.  Tristan replied there was a bug that square development had to fix.  I confirmed that the create checkout API is now working properly so this issue should be resolved now.

Comment: Actually, yes it does. I, too, have been in some communication with Tristan about this.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using your sandbox or production access tokens? I was able to generate a checkout form with the example postman request:

```
{
  "idempotency_key": "73ae1696-b1e3-4328-af6d-f1e04d947a13",
  "order": {
    "reference_id": "my-order-001",
    "line_items": [
      {
        "name": "line-item-1",
        "quantity": "1",
        "base_price_money": {
          "amount": 1599,
          "currency": "USD"
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "line-item-2",
        "quantity": "2",
        "base_price_money": {
          "amount": 799,
          "currency": "USD"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "ask_for_shipping_address": true,
  "merchant_support_email": "merchant+support@website.com",
  "pre_populate_buyer_email": "buyer@email.com",
  "pre_populate_shipping_address": {
    "address_line_1": "500 Electric Ave",
    "address_line_2": "Suite 600",
    "locality": "New York",
    "administrative_district_level_1": "NY",
    "postal_code": "10003",
    "first_name": "Jane",
    "last_name": "Doe"
  },
  "redirect_url": "https://merchant.website.com/order-confirm"
}
```

Comment: Sandbox token. I'll give it another try.

Comment: This is definitely not working for me. Is there something that I need to set up on my account? Something I'm missing? I _am_ using my sandbox token, and one of the sample databases' location ID.

Comment: That is strange, would you mind emailing me the the email address for the account so I could look for it in our logs? My contact info is in my profile.

Comment: I did send the email about a half hour ago. Hopefully to the right place.